# Why does 'should equal' appear in between for the output ? And why is it repeating?

Tags: python

```
def alphabet_position(text):
    a= range(1,27)
    z=""
    b=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    o=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
    for i in text:
        if i in b:
            k=b.index(i)
            z=z+" "+ str(a[k])
        elif i in o:
            k=o.index(i)
            z=z +" "+ str(a[k])
        else:
             pass

    return(z)
```

Output:

```
' 20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11' should equal '20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11'
```

Input:

```
test.assert_equals(alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."), "20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11")
```

Why does `'should equal'` appear in between for the output? And why is it repeating?

Comment: What is `test`?  Why are you calling `assert_equals`?

Comment: Apparently, that's what `test.assert_equals` outputs. This means your test failed because your string begins with a space, but the test says it mustn't.

Comment: `a[k] == k + 1` and the second will perform better for sure. Having `b` and `o` is redundant, use `text = text.lower()` at the start and you are done. `else: pass` is also not needed.

Comment: Hey, I just rolled back the post to [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57759195/2) cause you removed all the crucial info, which I assume was accidental. LMK otherwise. In any case, this code is incomplete, so you need to make a [mre].

Comment: if I get the question right I think the issue is the space preceeding the first number in the output string? Otherwise, the output is correct. The space is inserted by `z=z +" "+ str(a[k])`. Quick fix/hack: `return z.strip()`. Wouldn't suggest this as a solution though, better see [Adirio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57759532/10197418) for example (use a list and then ' '.join).

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was deleted because it wasn't an answer. By the time I replied there was no question so there was nothing to answer, but now there is:

You are asserting if they are equal. That menas that python will tell you if they are not equal, thats why it says they should be equal. The difference is the startign space.

Also, some code improvements:
 1. `a[k]` is exactly the same than `k + 1`, no need to store a range, and look in it every time when you can just increment `k` by 1.
 2. Having `b` and `o` is redundant, by lower-casing your input you get the desired result.
 3. `else: pass` is not needed.
 4. Module `strings` has a helpful string with all the lowercase letters.
 5. `return` is not a function, do not wrap it in parenthesis.
 6. By using `" ".join()` you will add spaces between the numbers but not at the start.

Thanks to @wjandrea for some of the improvements

```py
from string ascii_lowercase as lowercases

def alphabet_position(text):
    z = []
    for i in text.lower():
        if i in lowercases:
            z.append(str(lowercases.index(i) + 1))
    return " ".join(z)
```

Or with a generator instead of a `for` loop:

```py
from string ascii_lowercase as lowercases

def alphabet_position(text):
    return " ".join(str(lowercases.index(i) + 1) for i in text.lower() if i in lowercases)
```